# Appveyor not calling Nuget Pack

Tags: nuget-package, appveyor

On my Appveyor project [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/jayhilden/elmah-io-elasticsearch) I have it configured in the build with `Package NuGet projects` checked. And in my source code I have a `.csproj` with a matching `.nuspec` [here](https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.ElasticSearch/tree/master/Elmah.Io.ElasticSearch) but my build isn't calling `nuget pack` to create the `.nupkg` file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had an incorrect configuration in my `appveyor.yml` file.  I updated the file to be *only* this and it started working.

`version: '2.0.0.{build}-prerelease'
build:
  publish_nuget: true`